# How can I Post on a friend's wall programatically using PHP?

Tags: php, facebook

I saw this on my timeline. I have no intention of spamming anyone so please don't tell me that it is against policies. I just want to know how they do it.

Similar questions on this topic have answers and comments like it is not possible at all but I took this screenshot three days ago. Can it be done programatically using PHP?

[image]

Comment: No it is not possible

Comment: @WizKid how did that person do it then? I also see comments like this one on random pages on Facebook.

Comment: By doing stuff that is not allowed.

Comment: @WizKid Like what? I know it is against policies but I want to know how did they even do it?

Comment: I work at Facebook. I'm not going to tell you how to do things that will get you banned

Comment: Yup, I just checked out your profile. :)

Comment: maybe you authorized some weird app that posted on your wall. check your app logins - and while you are at it, change your fb password and activate login approvals (which is VERY important).

Comment: @luschn It is not my account. It was one of my friend's whose friend posted it on her wall (automatically).

Comment: ok, no clue how that worked, it should not work with the api. you should report that app to facebook.